# If $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2)$ then there is a subsequence such that $u_n(t)\rightharpoonup u(t)$ almost everywhere?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

If $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$.  Can we find a subsequence such that $u_{n_k}(t)\rightharpoonup u(t)$ almost everywhere on $[0,T]$?

I'm not sure if this question is trivial or not, and how to even start! Any hints would be great!

---

**Edit 1:**
I would add that $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

**Edit 2:** I want to apologize for the confusion caused by the symbol "$\rightharpoonup$", which means weak convergence. I used it under the assumption that it is standard.

Thank you for the counter-example and the answer. Bill Johnson mentioned in the comments that the sequence $\{t\mapsto \sin(nt)\}$ converges weakly in $L^2(0,T;L^2(0,1))$, but no subsequence has the sought after property.

Which urges the question: what is a non-trivial sufficient condition so that the question has a positive answer?

Comment: a sequence of scalar functions $\|u_n-u\|$ converges to 0 in measure, thus a subsequence converges to 0 a.e.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I don't think that's enough. The question is about weak convergence, where we do not have the convergence of $||u_n-u||$ to zero in measure.

Comment: Consider the Rademachers or $\sin (nt)$ sequence in $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: Ah, this symbol means weak convergence!

Comment: What about the [Aubin-Lions Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubin%E2%80%93Lions_lemma)? Would that be suifficient for your purpose?